# How to disable a Jenkins job via curl?

Tags: post, curl, jenkins

I want to disable a Jenkins job by sending a post curl request to Jenkins.

I've tried doing that using:

1. `curl -X POST http://<server>:8080/<jobname>/disable`
2. `curl -X POST http://<server>:8080/<jobname>/disable?token=<token>`
3. `curl -u <username>:<token> POST http://<server>:8080/<jobname>/disable`

but failed every time. The error i am getting is:

> 403 no valid crumb was included in the request

Is there a good curl based solution to this problem?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The crumb error indicates you are using [CSRF Protection](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Remote+access+API#RemoteaccessAPI-CSRFProtection). You need to include a proper crumb header in your request. The crumb can be obtained from the Jenkins API as described on the Jenkins wiki page linked above. The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23660988/172599) for "Trigger parameterized build with curl and crumb" shows the syntax to adding the crumb header in the curl request.

Comment: is the crumb data always fixed or I have to get it using a query everytime?

Comment: @rwt The crumb is mostly static, but it does depend on the username and client IP. If you're writing a script where those parameters will vary, you're better off requesting the crumb at the start of the script.

Answer (score 21):

No valid crumb means your Jenkins installation has a security option enabled which prevent requests send in a standard way to avoid [one-click attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery). You can't use Jenkins CLI either, because it [doesn't work yet](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-18114).

Here are the steps using `curl` (replace `localhost` with your Jenkins address):

1. Note your user API Token (from `/user/USER/configure`).
2. Get your crumb:

   ```
   CRUMB=$(curl -s 'http://USER:TOKEN@localhost:8080/crumbIssuer/api/xml?xpath=concat(//crumbRequestField,":",//crumb)')
   ```
3. Now you can disable the job by sending the crumb in the headers:

   ```
   curl -X POST -H "$CRUMB" http://USER:TOKEN@localhost:8080/<jobname>/disable
   ```

   <sup>If the above won't work for some reason, you may try to use `-u USER:TOKEN` instead.</sup>

Comment: Works great! Note that it might be cleaner to use `curl -u user:pass http://localhost:8080/...` instead of having the user/pass in the URL itself (depending on how you're scripting it).

Answer (score 4):

setup jenkins's "global security settings":
    Uncheck "Prevent Cross Site Request Forgery exploits"

Comment: Disabling CSRF protection opens a security hole and leaves your instance vulnerable to maliciously crafted links  https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)

Answer (score 3):

I found the first part of [kenorb's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38314286) worked for me, i.e. getting the crumb, but for the second part, curl did not like that syntax, it said:

> curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host 'http:'

So I had to use the following syntax which worked:

`curl -H $CRUMB http://localhost:8080/<jobname>/disable -u USER:TOKEN`

Comment: thank you, this is what i need in my java app, sending user:token in request header

Answer (score 1):

The below is working for me

```
curl -X POST http://<servername>/job/jobname/disable
```

Make sure the user access to do that.