# How to automate a Jenkins job to disable itself for a particular time period and then enable itself?

Tags: jenkins

Here is the use case.

Like I want a job should be disabled between 12:00 PM and 13:00 PM but after 13:00 PM, it should automatically enable itself. Is there any settings for this in Jenkins front end.

Help will be appreciated.

Comment: You could have another scheduled job that would do this for you. This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28577551/how-to-disable-a-jenkins-job-via-curl